# New XML document with Key / Value pairs

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I am fairly new to programing and I want to create a new key value pair document via xml to send to a web service

```
<BuildAddOns>
    <UserInput Question="foo" Answer="blahh" Type="String" />
    <UserInput Question="foo" Answer="blahh" Type="String" />
</BuildAddOns>
```

Comment: `I want to create a new key value pair document via xml to send to a web service`. And I want a computer that boots in 3 seconds. Interesting, but I'm not sure how this is a question.

Comment: Well my question is I want to create a new XML document that has a name/value pairing like above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `XDocument` to read/write a xml file. Here is the code:

```
XElement root = new XElement("BuildAddOns");

XDocument doc = new XDocument(root);


XElement element1 = new XElement("UserInput");
element1.SetAttributeValue("Question", "foo");
element1.SetAttributeValue("Answer", "blahh");
element1.SetAttributeValue("Type", "String");

doc.Root.Add(element1);

XElement element2 = new XElement("UserInput");
element2.SetAttributeValue("Question", "foo");
element2.SetAttributeValue("Answer", "blahh");
element2.SetAttributeValue("Type", "String");

doc.Root.Add(element2);

doc.Save(@"C:\New Text Document.txt");
```

Comment: Thanks but what about creating a new file that has the structure above